# e_mark_line symbol and name

Tags: r, visualization, echarts4r

How can I change the label of the line generated with e_mark_line?  Here is my attempt, instead of showing the number 200, I'd like it to have my own label.

```
library(echarts4r)
library(tidyverse)    

line <- list(
        xAxis = 200
        , name = "label 1"
    )

USArrests %>% 
  e_charts(Assault) %>% 
  e_scatter(Murder, Rape) %>% 
  e_mark_line(data = line, symbol = "none", name = "label 2")
```

[image: Chart generated by code]

Comment: can you please create a demo ?

Comment: OK - added library references - should be able to run this now.

Comment: Not able to run, can you create a working instance of your code ?

Comment: @JasdeepSingh perhaps you need to install the libraries.

Comment: Can you please try:
 e_mark_line(data = line, symbol = "none", label = "custom label")

Comment: I've tried that and many others and it doesn't work - if you get it to work, let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The underlying echarts JavaScript to mark lines, points and areas is rather convoluted. The title must be specified in the `data`. In the dev version there are convenience `title` related arguments.

```
library(echarts4r)

cars %>% 
  e_charts(speed) %>% 
  e_scatter(dist, symbol_size = 5) %>% 
  e_legend(FALSE) %>% 
  # manual
  e_mark_line(data = list(xAxis = 7, symbol = "rect", label = list(formatter = "tortoise"))) %>%
  # convenience arguments in latest github version
  e_mark_line(data = list(xAxis = 12), title = "Speed Limit") %>% 
  e_mark_line(data = list(xAxis = 22), title = "Need for Speed")
```